# Vue.js/NativeScript: Nesting other components from a parent component or conditionally loading components from app.js?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, vue-component, nativescript-vue

Is there a preferred architecture when writing mobile apps with `nativescript-vue`?

Is it preferable to have ONE base component which loads all the time and then have that component be responsible for nesting other components? 
Or is it preferable to do what I did below and have app.js take care of which component to load?

```
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue';

import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld';
import Second from './components/Second';

new Vue({

    template: `
        <Frame>
            <FirstMain @change-to-second="changeToSecond" v-if="this.showIt"/>
            <SecondMain v-if="!this.showIt"/>
        </Frame>`,

    components: {
        FirstMain,
        SecondMain
    },
    data() {
        return {
            showIt: true
        }
    },
    methods: {
        changeToSecond: function () {
            console.log("testing")
            this.showIt = false;
        }
    }
}).$start();
```

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow; your question seems to be asking for an opinion, and SO isn't really the place for those types of questions;  but someone might have a solid, empirical answer for you;  you can help by re-phrasing your question about the specific trade-offs you are concerned about; that makes for a more robust question that folks can help guide you on

Comment: Thanks @landru27!  I wasn't sure if it was an opinion or if one of the ways was totally wrong.  Thank you!

Comment: I don't think that really matters, whichever way you follow, at the end webpack is going to bundle all your components into one file unless you use async components, the whole code is loaded at one shot.